# Gradle build errors while integrating DroidAR in an android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality

We have guidelines for integrating DroidAR in an Eclipse project provided at this link: [DroidAR Mobile Augmented Reality - How to use the framework in your own application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFbEvkWJOV0) but I am struggling with setting up DroidAR in an AndroidStudio project.

The steps which I followed are:

1. Downloaded DroidAR from this link - [DroidAR](https://bitstars.github.io/droidar/)
2. Created a new android studio project - DroidArSample
3. Imported droidar folder (found within downloaded archive, step 2) as a new module in DroidArSample
4. Added droidar as a dependency to DroidArSample
5. Removed icon related attribute from droidar/AndroidManifest.xml
6. Compiled

It is showing 120 compilation errors, few errors specified below:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/devarshi.k/Downloads/DroidArSample/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/res/values-ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/devarshi.k/Downloads/DroidArSample/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/res/values-ldrtl-v23/values-ldrtl-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:textAlignment\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/devarshi.k/Downloads/DroidArSample/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/res/values-v17/values-v17.xml","position":{"startLine":5,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":407,"endColumn":41,"endOffset":428}}],"original":""}
```

Final FAILED message is:

```
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/devarshi.k/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your build.gradle?

Comment: Here is the link for gradle: https://github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/DroidArSample/blob/master/build.gradle, here is the link of its code base: https://github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/DroidArSample/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `build.gradle` file for **mismatch of versions** between the following:

1. `compileSdkVersion`
2. `buildToolsVersion`
3. `targetSdkVersion`
4. Included app compat library e.g. `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`

**It is recommended to set all of them to the same version to avoid issues like mentioned in your question**.

**E.g.** If you go with API Level-23 your configuration in `build.gradle` should be as seen below:

*(in the respective places each of the following is declared)*

```
compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

targetSdkVersion 23

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

[Refererence](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/hello-there-brand-new-whiner-here-im-getting-3-errors-when-attempting-to-run-my-funfacts-app)

Answer (score 1):

i downloaded your project from GitHub and edited the build.gradle in this way:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    ...

defaultConfig {
        applicationId "daemonconstruction.droidarsample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
     dependencies {
       ...
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
       ...
}
```

}

Sync, rebuild the project and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add next line into your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' // write your encoding here
    ...
}
```